# asp.net mvc avoid duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a Users table in which no two same users can exists , what is the best way to do this error free?

What I did is that I wrote a check for duplication in the controller, but someone said to me it's not a right thing to do. He said put unique on database table? I have implemented this on several other controllers as well. Do I ought to change it?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am using linq to sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several places where you should do this.

- at database table level: Use email as username and mark it as unique constrant
- at model validation level you can check for the email and return validation error
- at client side, you can place some code using async request that will check for duplicate email or username in real time when user enters username in textbox

-- edit --

It is suggested to place all three for better validations. Inconsistent data is the worst thing for your system than anything else. Because what I think is, correct data = good quality

-- end edit --

please keep in mind that validation code should be placed at model and to learn how to write manageable OO code you can see example of [mvc store front](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/18861).

hope this will help

Comment: Client side method is good, but can easily result in taking database of users or their emails from you, so I would not recomend it.

Comment: @Migol, Agree with you. There are ways to prevent it as well, but you are right, you should keep this in mind

Comment: Db constraints are terrible to do this type of work with IF you expect to bubble the error message up throughout your code.  Everything then becomes dependent on some type of "error messaging" service.

Comment: @jfar, I didn't mean only db constraint, I mean all of three. because even if you are having good front end code to validate everything correctly, you should also have db constraints in there, that will help you when your app needs import/exports

Answer (score 5):

It is much better to enforce your data constraints at a database level, wherever possible.  consider the following situation:

2 requests to create a user with the same name, at around the same time.

1. Request 1 checks DB to see if exists - user does not;
2. Shortly after, request 2 checks DB to see if exists - user does not;
3. Request 1 creates this user.
4. Request 2 creates a duplicate user.
5. Bang.  Everything stops working the way you expect it to.

As for whether to use a unique constraint, or to have this as a primary key, is another question and very much depends on your situation (because you do have a primary key of some kind on this table, don't you?)

Comment: @Migol, I would agree, but the database is still the place for this constraint, regardless of whether the front end uses transactions or not.

Comment: Erm, upvote but one issue, you'd want to use a unique constraint - because you really don't want to use a "real" value as a primary key.

Comment: @Murph - that's generally my point of view as well, but given the question, was curious as to whether there was any kind of key on this table (there should really be something).

Comment: Fair point - if there isn't add one (but don't use the username!)